# Logcat shows nothing in mac OS X

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

When I run my code,logcat shows nothing but empty. I tried restarting android studio still nothing happened. Any suggestions?

Comment: Any filters on your logcat?

Comment: It shows "Show only selected Application".

Comment: In the first instance, I’d turn off all filters and see if your device is saying anything at all. Then narrow it down from there.

Comment: That didn't help me.

Comment: In that case, I suggest you add more information to your question. Do you have simple code? Does it have log statements in it? Are you using a device or an emulator? Does your code run on the device/emulator? Android studio version? Operating system? The lack of information is probably why the question is currently downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the solution, the problem was in search bar in logcat. The search bar should be empty but in my case it was written "okHttp". 
Maybe it helps anyone.